# HTTPS indexing after migration

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, https

I moved my website from HTTP to HTTPS version month ago, and I made all necessary changes, I made 301 redirect so all old links redirect to the HTTPS version, and I added the new version to webmaster tools, submitted a new sitemap, and made all needed changes to my site, also changed all internal links to HTTPS, after that everything was just fine my site links in google changed to HTTPS and the visits to the HTTP version become fewer every day, but I was surprised when I saw my links in google changed to http again after that and visits to HTTP version rise day by day as you can see in the pic, 301 redirect working perfectly, now what I have to do to make the links appear in HTTPS version in google? any one can help me ?

[image]

Comment: Have you removed the old sitemap from the http version and also updated your robots.txt to represent the new sitemap url ?

Comment: thank you for replying, no i didn't removed the old sitemap because experts in google productforums saying it's better to keep them for few weeks, and i have updated robots firle to https version

Comment: Are you sure you set up all your redirects properly? Also for the homepage? Have you added Strict Transport Security header?

Comment: @tobiv Hi, all pages redirecting perfectly, i use Cloudflare ssl, i found out that i didn't activate 2 options (HSTS) and Automatic HTTPS Rewrites i think this is the cause of the problem do you agree ?

Comment: Yes, if you activate these options you should be good.

Comment: thanks for helping me, i activated them, but is HSTS option is necessary ?

Comment: HSTS isn't _necessary_ but it does help browsers know not to keep trying HTTP on the same domain. It can help users have a slightly quicker experience.

Answer (score 2):

use the .htaccess to force redirect to https, so that every visitor (including Google's index, gets the correct version):

Add this to the top of your .htaccess file:

> RewriteEngine On  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
>   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80  RewriteRule ^(.*)$
>   https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

*be sure to replace www.example.com w/ your domain name, same goes for example.com

Answer (score 1):

If all the links are redirected properly then you should have no traffic on the http pages.

Looks like this is a screenshot from Search Console. Did you set the preferred version of your site to the https version in SC site settings?

Comment: In Google Search Console, you are able to specify which version of the domain is the preferred one. You might have four domain properties to choose from if you set them all up. https/http/www/non-www

Comment: ah i get you, i tried to find this option but i couldn't see it in Search Console,